# Show a website with Woocommerce in an iframe and the purchase process works

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, woocommerce, x-frame-options

I would like to be able to put a website with Woo commerce in an iframe so that people buy products as if it were on my website, The website where the iframe goes does not have to be a WordPress installation. The problem is that when navigating inside the iframe in the tests that I have done, problems with directives `"X-Frame-Options", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"` and `"Content-Security-Policy"` appear that do not allow navigation. How can this be resolved?

Comment: What are the values for the `X-Frame-Options`, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Content-Security-Policy` headers. Also: are you able to modify the headers of the site in the frame?

Comment: Content-Security-Policy child-src 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' http: https: data: mediastream: *.divertisenvivo.com; frame-ancestors 'strict-dynamic' 'report-sample' http: https: data: mediastream: *.divertisenvivo.com; frame-src http: https: data: mediastream: *.divertisenvivo.com; worker-src http: https: data: mediastream: *.divertisenvivo.com

X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies all

Comment: Could you add these to your post with proper formatting? They're hard to read as you've written them down here. I believe the most important one will be [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors). Also, if this is a wordpress specific problem, are you aware that there is a https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 0):

I have done it through a Wordpress plugin, I attach an image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS9JG.png)

Comment: What plugin did u used?

Comment: If there s more info,  I have same issue

Answer (score 0):

I think adding this in the PHP configuration works:

Header always edit Set-Cookie (. *) "$ 1; SameSite = None; Secure