# Woocommerce website to Iframe rendering - Unable to do add to cart and purchase it

Tags: php, iframe, woocommerce

I am trying to render my website on a mobile device through an iframe, it's working perfectly but when I add products to the cart, then it causes issues, unable to add to the cart and purchase it.

This is my iframe in home page
`<iframe class="full-height" src="https://wp-developer.online/"  width="100%"></iframe>`

My Website showing but i am unable to make purchase and add to cart

Please resolve me , this task is very important in my office , i should resolve it , otherwise i lose the job , please resolve this is possible

my products should be add in cart and purchase through it , using iframe

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: From what i see you dont have payment methods. And you can check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66313114/show-a-website-with-woocommerce-in-an-iframe-and-the-purchase-process-works.

Comment: I am guessing that most likely you have a problem with 3rd-party cookie getting blocked in this scenario, so that WP can't keep a session - and therefor no cart content either.

Comment: @martin I saw the url you given and I tried it too , but wont working for me , please give me some solution please

Comment: @CBroe you do know this to issue brother ? is it possible to solve it ? i am deadend in my office whether I didn't solve this issue , please tell me the ways that woocommerce website will run any iframe

Answer (score 0):

Your issue seems to be related to browser cookies and security issues.

You can check this [WooCommerce plugin support forum post](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/not-able-to-add-something-to-cart-shop-is-in-iframe/) for more details.

For the solution, you can try this [gist code](https://gist.github.com/AndreiTelteu/d306288fa8770228c3c16f79c7b5b245)
I have not tested the solution but you can give it a try. Make sure you have full back and FTP access if you're going to try the code in the live/functional website.

Comment: thanks to replay , i am checking now which you suggested , ill get back to you with good news I hope

Comment: brother i have tried gist code link which you provided , it sometimes only working add to cart , suddenly showing season expired return to cart , and some time not adding cart products , working only some times... what to do now brother ?

Comment: i am a full stack developer , i have all access sections keys , is there any way by changing web admin sections ?